# What is the normative rule in the current draft rules that a template parameter pack which does not participate in deduction is deduced to empty

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename ...T, typename U>
void fun(U){}
int main(){
   fun(0);
}
```

This snippet code is accepted by both GCC and Clang. The template parameter pack `T` does not participate in the template argument deduction in the context of function call, as per the following rules:
[[temp.deduct.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#1)

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each **function template parameter type** (call it P) that **contains template-parameters** that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

The pack `T` is contained by any function template parameter. If there were no other special rules specify, the deduction would fail according to:
[[temp.deduct.type#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#2)

> if any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.

However, such a case is ruled by the following rule in the current standard, that is:
[[temp.arg.explicit#4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.explicit#4)

> A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) **not otherwise deduced** will **be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments**.

So, the above case can be considered to deduce successfully which leaves the pack `T` with an empty set of template arguments.

However, the special rule in temp.arg.explicit#4 has been changed to a note in the current draft

[[temp.arg.explicit#note-1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#note-1)

> [Note 1: A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments. — end note]

So, I wonder Is there any alternative normative rule in the current draft states that the pack `T` not otherwise deduced  will be deduced to an empty set of template arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The previously normative section of [temp.arg.explicit]/4

> [...] A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments. [...]

was made into a non-normative note as part of [P1787R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html).

As you've pointed out, as per [[temp.deduct.type]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> Type deduction is done independently for each `P`/`A` pair [...], if **any template argument** remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.

[[temp.arg.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.general) describes that a template parameter that is a template parameter pack may correspond to zero *template arguments*:

> [...] When the parameter declared by the template is a template parameter pack, it will correspond to **zero** or more **template-arguments**.

and [[temp.variadic]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#1) explicitly mention that a template parameter pack may *accept* zero arguments:

> A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments.

followed by a non-normative example of an empty argument list for an entity templated over a parameter pack template parameter:

> ```
> template<class ... Types> struct Tuple { };
> Tuple<> t0;  // Types contains no arguments
> ```

Now, returning to [[temp.arg.explicit]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.explicit#4):

> **If all of the** template **arguments** can be deduced, **they may all be omitted**; in this case, **the empty template argument list `<>` itself may also be omitted.**

Meaning the `Tuple` example above is can likewise omit the empty argument list

> ```
> Tuple t0;  // Also OK: Types contains no arguments
> ```

but where the key is that, as per [temp.arg.general] above, that a template parameter list may correspond to zero arguments, in which case there are no template arguments needed to be deduced.

If you look at your own example:

> ```
> template<typename ...T, typename U>
> void fun(U){}
> int main(){
>    fun(0);  // #1
> }
> ```

you could likewise invoke `#1` as:

```
fun<>(0);  // argument list for parameter pack is empty
           // -> no argument (beyond that for `U`) to deduce
```

highlighting that the deducible argument corresponding to the template parameter `U` can be omitted from the explicit template-arguments, whereas the remaining template-arguments *are none*; namely, the argument list for the template parameter that is a template parameter pack *is empty*, and there are thus no remaining template arguments that needs to be deduced.

Thus

> A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments.

is non-normative/redundant, explaining why it was wrapped into a *[Note - [...] - end note]*.

Comment: I'm not saying this is wrong, but I think it would help to discuss cases (1) the template parameter pack is not used in a deducible context in the function parameter list and (2) the template parameter pack is used in a deducible context in the function parameter list, and there are zero corresponding function arguments in a call expression. Apparently both satisfy [temp.arg.explicit]/4 "if all of the template arguments can be deduced"?

Comment: @aschepler (1) would be entirely covered by answer above, if I am not mistaken, whereas (2) is covered by the above + [\[temp.variadic\]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#2), and [\[temp.variadic\]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#8), which covers that (/2) a _function parameter pack_ may accept zero arguments and (/8) the effect on an enclosing construct (say the function template, and which specialization it refers to) for the case where a function parameter pack is empty ("N is zero").

Comment: @dfrib What I cannot understand is that, "correspond to zero or more template-arguments" means, if a template parameter pack that does not participate in deduction is deduced to an empty. Such as `Tuple<>`, the pack does correspond to zero arguments in this case, In other words, Pi deduced from Ai which is empty. In my example, the pack does not appear in any `P` at all. In my mind, the deduction is an action that compares P with A.

Comment: @jackX I think it's clear from [temp.variadic]/1, /2 and /8 that the _template argument list_ will be empty if there no arguments are either provided explicitly via the template argument list or via expansion and deduction of an associated function parameter pack. I none of these apply, the template parameter that is a parameter pack corresponds to zero template arguments, and there are thus no template arguments (from the pack) into which deduction can be applied. I would like to argue that "deduce" as used in the now non-normative note is a bit unfortunate: there is no argument deduction ...

Comment: ... here, but simply the rules of variadic templates, such that there will be no template arguments associated with the template parameter pack (and there is no P/A deduction in action).

Comment: @dfrib Yes, that `note` indicates that the standard admits that whatever these template parameters for which there's no argument explicitly specified are necessary to be deduced

Comment: @jackX Seems like an editorial issue in the (C++20) normative text / (current draft) non-normative text; afaict it should read something like _"A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced **will result in** an empty sequence of template arguments."_.

Comment: @dfrib  Do you mean those template parameters to which there shall be one template argument corresponds, its template argument should be either explicitly specified or be deduced. Instead, a template parameter pack can correspond to zero template argument, in which case there's no template argument that needs to be deduced at all?

Comment: @jackX Exactly; dection is always through P/A pairing (even if it can be "recursive" e.g. for deduction in specializations), and with a template parameter that is a template parameter pack, the case of zero template arguments means there are no P/A pair to deduce. Rather, the _rules_ of variadic templates states when a template parameter pack is considered to be empty.

Comment: @dfrib After thinking it a moment, I think the obscure point is the case of zero number of template arguments is required, it sounds like vacuous truth; namely, each template argument of the required template argument set shall be deduced, where the set is empty.

Comment: The `Tuple t0;` case is actually class template argument deduction; [temp.arg.explicit] applies only to function templates.

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right, thanks. Would you say my argument for the _[Note ... end note]_ wrapping of yours in P1787R6 is otherwise sound, or a) are there other relevant sections I'm missing, or b) was there another reason (as opposed to "this is already in normative text elsewhere")? I'm also wondering, as xmh0511, whether "deduced" is the correct term to use in the context of "deduced as an empty sequence" (i.e. deduction without P/A pairs), or if it's rather the result of the rules of variadic templates.